# React/ Redux select filtering and sorting using selectors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have a list of items that I would like the user to be able to sort and filter by attribute. I figure using selectors is the most efficient way to do this, though I am not sure exactly how? Ideally, I would like the user to select an attribute from a dropdown above the list, then enter the actual value of the attribute into a text field which would trigger a filtering selector using both of those params. For example in a list of cars, the user wants to filter by "make" so they choose "make" from a list of other attributes like "make", "model", "year" etc. and then next to that they could type in "Nissan" and then they get a list of just cars made by Nissan.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchItems } from "../../actions/items";

const ItemList = ({ match }) => {
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.items);
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchItems());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const renderedList =
    Object.values(items).length > 0
      ? Object.values(items)
          .map((item) => {
           
            return (
              <ListItem key={item.id}>
                <ItemCard item={item} handleClick={handleClick} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })
      : null;

  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" className={classes.cardGrid}>
      <Grid item lg={4} className={classes.list}>
       
        <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.title}>
          Items
        </Typography>
        <List dense>{renderedList}</List>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the filter attribute and value in Redux state, and then apply the filtering in a selector.

```js
// selectors.js

const getFilterAttribute = state => state.filterAttribute;
const getFilterValue = state => state.filterValue;

const getFilteredItems = state => {
  const filterAttribute = getFilterAttribute(state);
  const filterValue = getFilterValue(state);
  const items = getItems(state);
  
  if (!filterAttribute || !filterValue) {
    return items;
  }
  
  // apply your filter the way you need it
  return Object.values(items).filter(...)
}
```

This helps separate the state-selection logic from the presentation logic. Now your component just has to call the selector:

```js
// ItemList.js

const ItemList = (props) => {
  const items = useSelector(getFilteredItems);
  const renderedList = items.map(item => ...)
  
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

EDIT:

The filter component might look like:

```
const FilterControl = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [attribute, setAttribute] = useState('');
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const onSubmit = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_FILTER', attribute, value });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Attribute</label>
      <input value={attribute} onChange={e => setAttribute(e.target.value)} />

      <label>Value</label>
      <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Filter</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Wow that's neat, but I am confused to as to how I would actually get the attribute and value into state in the first place. Would I do something like `const [filterAttribute, setFilterAttribute] = useState("")`  in my list component? And then have the set hook run onChange in when selecting an attribute or typing in a value?

Comment: yes that sounds about right. Putting that stuff into its own component might help. I added some more example code to the post for reference

Comment: Haha ooh boy now I'm more confused. Why am I dispatching actions? I thought I was using this pattern to avoid those. Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: well, I might not have been completely clear. You store the filter settings in the Redux state. To change the values, you have to dispatch an action. Contrarily, if you were to store the filter settings in local component state, then the approach would look a bit different.

Comment: So is it better practice to store the filter settings in redux state? I'm guessing yes